# Cloned element with the same function and style being positioned in different places?

Tags: javascript, clone

I currently have a set of codes that act on table cells, when clicking a table cell the entire row's children cells get removed and the clicked cell gets cloned to the leftmost position, spanning the entire row. However, what I noticed was while on the first row all the cloned images get positioned in the right place, that is in the original position of the leftmost table cell in the row, it doesn't go the same way on the second row. The cloned element's position deviates a bit to the top right corner. Currently I have all the elements having the same width and height so I don't think that's the problem, and I only have universal table styles applied to the table. So I'm not sure what makes the image not get cloned to the right position.

HTML:

```
    <table id='TrendGames'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="cell1">
                <img class='GameCover' src='Fortnite Front Cover.png' alt="cell1" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell2">
                <img class='GameCover' src='LOL Front Cover.png' alt="cell2" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell3">
                <img class='GameCover' src='Minecraft Front Cover.png' alt="cell3" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell4">
                <img class='GameCover' src='Roblox Front Cover.png' alt="cell4" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="cell1"> Cell 1
                <img class='GameCover' src='Call of Duty Front Cover.jpg' alt="cell1" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell2">Cell 2
                <img class='GameCover' src='Valorant Front Cover.jpg' alt="cell2" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell3">Cell 3
                <img class='GameCover' src='Counter Strike 2 Front Cover.jpeg' alt="cell3" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell4">Cell 4
                <img class='GameCover' src='The Sim 4 Front Cover.webp' alt="cell4" />
                </td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    padding: 45px;
}
```

javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let table = document.getElementById('TrendGames');
  table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let clickedCell = event.target.closest('td');
    if (clickedCell) {
      handleCellClick(clickedCell);
    }
  });
});

function handleCellClick(clickedCell) {
  const row = clickedCell.parentElement;
  const cells = row.children;
  const display = cells[cells.length - 1].style.display ? '' : 'none';

  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.display = display;
  }
  if (display) { 
    const newCell = clickedCell.cloneNode(true);
    newCell.style.display = '';
    newCell.colSpan = cells.length;
    row.insertBefore(newCell, row.firstChild);
    openSlider(newCell);
  } else {
    clickedCell.remove();
    closeSlider(clickedCell);
  }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in the second row seems to affect the layout within the cell. You could consider adding a line break (`<br/>`) after the text, to ensure that the text does not affect the vertical position due to its vertical text alignment and to ensure that the width of the table cell content (and by extension, the table cell itself) remains constant.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let table = document.getElementById('TrendGames');
  table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let clickedCell = event.target.closest('td');
    if (clickedCell) {
      handleCellClick(clickedCell);
    }
  });
});

function handleCellClick(clickedCell) {
  const row = clickedCell.parentElement;
  const cells = row.children;
  const display = cells[cells.length - 1].style.display ? '' : 'none';

  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.display = display;
  }
  if (display) {
    const newCell = clickedCell.cloneNode(true);
    newCell.style.display = '';
    newCell.colSpan = cells.length;
    row.insertBefore(newCell, row.firstChild);
    // openSlider(newCell);
  } else {
    clickedCell.remove();
    // closeSlider(clickedCell);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 45px;
}
```

```html
<table id='TrendGames'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1">
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100' alt="cell1" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell2">
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100?' alt="cell2" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell3">
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100?0' alt="cell3" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell4">
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100?1' alt="cell4" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1"> Cell 1<br/>
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100?2' alt="cell1" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell2">Cell 2<br/>
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100?3' alt="cell2" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell3">Cell 3<br/>
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100?4' alt="cell3" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell4">Cell 4<br/>
        <img class='GameCover' src='https://picsum.photos/100/100?5' alt="cell4" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```